# Connect to Postgres on Mac osX

Tags: macos, postgresql

Part of an install includes a postgres database install.  The database is running and the App that uses it is connecting fine.

I want to use the postgres install for some of my own reporting needs.  I've got a fair way to getting to the database but I am stumped at the last bit.

I can do a `psql -h /path/to/socket` but get

```
psql: FATAL: authentication failed for user "postgres": invalid authentication method.
```

I have gone in to the `pg_hba.conf` and the only lines not commented are:

```
 local   all   all                 trust
 host    all   all   127.0.0.1/32  trust
 host    all   all   ::1/128       trust
```

As far as I can see this should mean any local attempt at connection would be trusted and therefore OK.

I've tried with specifying different users (root, me, etc) and always get the same reply.  Any ideas how I can access the server?

Comment: If you are attempting to use Apple's built-in PostgreSQL (from Server.app) ... don't.  Bad idea. Install your own. See this recent issue for details: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/148877/21183

Comment: No - not trying to use Apple's build in - but another instance that is installed by an App I'm using

Comment: I think we'd need to know more about this instance you're using then. Version, if it has any patches, how you compiled it if you did or where the binaries/installer came from, etc. Also is there any more detail in the server error log? Are you sure you're looking at the right `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Its V 8.4
As far as I can tell (I did a find / -name pg_hba.conf) there is only one pg_hba.conf file on my mac.
Just tried changing it to
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust

No difference. Sorry I sam a bit of a newbe on postgres.

Comment: Is the pg_hba.conf the only file that "secures" the local server?

Comment: Well, there's also `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`, but mostly yes. Some settings are also applied at the SQL level - `GRANT`, `ALTER USER`, etc.